# POST request in React js

Tags: reactjs, http

Why do the following request work:

```
curl -d username=user@user.com -d password=user -L http://localhost:8081
```

but this (React js) do not?:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8081',{
            username: values.email,
            password: values.password}).then(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log(response.data);
                setRedirect(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            }});
```

Comment: What is the outcome?

Comment: Status 302, method POST, then as response from server Status 200 and /?error, method GET. When I send the same thru CURL it responses with my desired success-page. (Spring Security)

Comment: Try adding `.exceptionHandling().and().cors().and().csrf().disable();` to your Spring Security configuration (at the end).

Comment: Doesn't change anything.. Anyone?

Comment: Turns out Spring Security accepts only pure text in the form: "username:myusr&password:mypwd"